# How to compare two vectors of the same length in R, but not object by object

Tags: r

Example: I have two vector with the following structure (also they can be two columns of a data frame).

```
A <- c("a", "d", "f", "a", "n", "d", "d")

B <- c("h xx", "a xxx", "f xxxx", "d xxxxx", "a xxx", "h xx", "f xxxx")
```

I need compare the two vectors of shape that if an object of A if equal to first element of an object of B, 
replace that object of A with the object of B.
For the example presented above,  the object `A[1]` that is `a`, will match with the `B[2]` that is `a xxx`, so object `A [1]`, will be replaced for object `B[2]`. 
Finally `A` would be with the following elements: `"a xxx" "d xxxxx" "f xxxx" "a xxx" "n" "d xxxxx" "d xxxxx"`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `%in%` and `match` like this:

```
A[A %in% substr(B, 1, 1)] <- B[match(A, substr(B, 1, 1), nomatch=FALSE)]
A
[1] "a xxx"   "d xxxxx" "f xxxx"  "a xxx"   "n"       "d xxxxx" "d xxxxx"
```

Here, `%in%` selects the positions of A to replace, and `match` finds the proper order of replacement. The `nomatch=FALSE` is used so that elements in A that are not in B are ignored rather than returning NA, which is the default. `substr` is used to pull out the first character of B for matching.

Comment: as always you always give concise ones !! +1!

Answer (score 1):

logic : we iterate through each of `A` and then using `grepl` we get the indices from `B`.

```
sapply(A,  function(x) {if(any(grepl(x, B))) x <- B[grepl(x, B)][1];x})
#        a         d         f         a         n         d         d 
#  "a xxx" "d xxxxx"  "f xxxx"   "a xxx"       "n" "d xxxxx" "d xxxxx"
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi is this what you are looking for:

```
for(i in 1:length(A)){
  for(j in 1:length(B)){
    if(A[i] == substr(B[j], 1, 1)){
       A[i] <- B[j]
    }
  }
}

# [1] "a xxx"   "d xxxxx" "f xxxx"  "a xxx"   "n"       "d xxxxx" "d xxxxx"
```